# Empty lines appears in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

When I go to add data in first row there is empty lines that appear below my code, why do these lines appear? I need only to add data in one row and save it.

```
    Dim pringdata As String = "SELECT * FROM itemInfo  "

    Dim sqlconload As New SqlConnection(sqlcon)

    Try
        sqlconload.Open()

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(pringdata, sqlconload)
        ds.Clear()
        da.Fill(ds, "itemInfo")

        Dim rowcount As Integer
        rowcount = ds.Tables("itemInfo").Rows.Count
        If rowcount >= 1 Then

            DGVorders.Rows.Add(rowcount)
            For i = 0 To rowcount - 1
                If DGVorders.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = ds.Tables("itemInfo").Rows(i).Item("itemCode") Then
                    DGVorders(1, e.RowIndex).Value = ds.Tables("itemInfo").Rows(i).Item("itemName")
                    DGVorders(2, e.RowIndex).Value = ds.Tables("itemInfo").Rows(i).Item("Uint1")
                    DGVorders(4, e.RowIndex).Value = ds.Tables("itemInfo").Rows(i).Item("price1")

                End If
            Next
        End If

        sqlconload.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the "AllowUsersToAddRows" property to remove that blank line.
Example:

DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False

Answer (score 0):

`DGVorders.Rows.Add(rowcount)` will add `rowcount` amount of empty rows to your DataGridView. I don't know why you are doing that, it's not as if you are adding values to the cells in those new rows in your for loop.

updated

```
If dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = ds.Tables("itemInfo").Rows(i)("itemCode") Then
Dim newRow As DataGridViewRow = TryCast(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Clone(), DataGridViewRow)
newRow.Cells(1).Value = ds.Tables("itemInfo").Rows(i)("itemName")
newRow.Cells(2).Value = ds.Tables("itemInfo").Rows(i)("Uint1")
newRow.Cells(3).Value = ds.Tables("itemInfo").Rows(i)("price1")
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(newRow)
```

End If

Comment: I added this because I want to type "item code" in the first cell and some cells appear the value direct from ds like" item name , unit ,...."

Comment: Why not just add a row if you find a match? Edited answer